# Image is not visible after sharing via intent in Nougat devices only

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-7.0-nougat

Guys i have been facing an issue regarding sharing image in **nougat** devices but don't know why after choose a sharing app(ex-facebook) ,my image is not visible. Here is a screenshot below

[image]

```
  share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            Bitmap bitmap = viewToBitmap(canvas);
            shareBitmap(bitmap, timeStamp + ".png");
        }
    });


    private void shareBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
    try {

        File file = new File(getCacheDir(), fileName + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception :>>", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

By Using FileProvider:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

provider_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

save_share.java

```
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
            Bitmap bitmap = viewToBitmap(canvas);
            shareBitmap(bitmap, timeStamp + ".png");
        }
    });


    private void shareBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String fileName) {
    try {

        File file = new File(getCacheDir(), fileName + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        file.setReadable(true, false);
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(save_share.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        final Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoURI);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("exception :>>", e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is only happen with **Nougat** devices. Please help me to find a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is only happen with Nougat devices.

You have stored the image on your app's portion of internal storage, which is inaccessible to other apps.

You have attempted to overcome this by calling `setReadable(true, false)`. This is insecure, as it allows any app to read this file. And, as of Android 7.0, IIRC, `setReadable()` can no longer be used.

Use `FileProvider` to share the content with other apps.

Comment: I have tried FileProvider also but could not able to open share dialog with it, see i updated my code

Comment: @Sudhansu: Well, among other possible problems, your `provider_paths.xml` is wrong. It says that your file is on external storage, and it is not. Use `<cache-path>`, as [the `FileProvider` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles) shows, which maps to the `getCacheDir()` that you are using.

Comment: @Sudhansu: `name` is whatever you want that is a valid `Uri` path segment. `path` is not necessary in your case.

Comment: But my main point is that what would i mention in **path** if my path is  InternalStorage > Pictures > myapp

Comment: @Sudhansu: I do not know what "InternalStorage > Pictures > myapp" means, sorry.

Comment: this is the path where pictures are stored

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure to run the app in release mode as the process might be killed when it is in the background.
- This solution is compatible with Android 4+ devices.
- Example of using FileProvider to share an image with a third party viewer: https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/t...ut-fileuriexposedexception.72538/#post-461501
- Example of sharing a file (any file): https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/share-txt-files.73166/#post-464921files.73166/#post-464921

Comment: "Make sure to run the app in release mode as the process might be killed when it is in the background." - is that relevant?